# How drop first occurence of tuple based on similar key value in Haskell using pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to drop the first occurence of tuple based on first value of tuple.
my plan is to go through the list of tuples and see if the key is present in the rest of the list, if it is there then return the rest of the list and look for other duplicates otherwise add the element to returned list.

```
duplicate [(x,_):xs]= if (elem (x,_) xs ) 
                      then xs 
                      else x ++ duplicate xs
```

I hope this makes sense, and thank you for any help.

Comment: You should give your functions type signatures, post the error messages you get, and why you don't understand the error message. In this case it looks like you wrote `duplicate [(x,_):xs]` when you meant `duplicate ((x,_):xs)` for one thing. Open ghci and type things like `:t elem`, `:t [0]`, etc. while you're developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to Haskell so please correct me if i am wrong. In this type of problem my JavaScript instincts tell me to use a Map or Hash. However when i check the `Data.Map` library i have noticed that it's a tree implementation and lookups are like O(log n). So i thought it might be similar in performance if i use `sortOn` instead. Any further info on this is highly appreciated.

So my solution would be;

```
dropFirstDupe :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
dropFirstDupe []  = []
dropFirstDupe [t] = [t]
dropFirstDupe ts  | fst t1 == fst t2 = dropFirstDupe (t2:tr)
                  | otherwise        = t1 : dropFirstDupe (t2:tr)
                  where (t1:t2:tr)   = sortOn fst ts

*Main> dropFirstDupe [(1,2),(3,6),(8,7),(1,5),(3,3),(7,9)]
[(1,5),(3,3),(7,9),(8,7)]
```

Note: If there exists more than 2 duplicates then it will keep the last one.

Well on a second thought i guess in the above snippet I am running the `sortOn` function in every turn of the recursion which is totally unnecessary. So a more efficient version of the above code should be;

```
dropFirstDupe :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
dropFirstDupe []  = []
dropFirstDupe ts  = dfd (sortOn fst ts)
                    where dfd [t]        = [t]
                          dfd (t1:t2:tr) | fst t1 == fst t2 = dfd (t2:tr)
                                         | otherwise        = t1 : dfd (t2:tr)
```

Comment: Thank you @Redu it that close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW I have also added a more efficient code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively simple yet inefficient (quadratic time) solution, you could do the following:

```
removeFirstDuplicate :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]                                                                                                                                                    
removeFirstDuplicate [] = []
removeFirstDuplicate (hd@(x, _):tl) =
    let
        rest = removeFirstDuplicate tl
    in
        if x `elem` (map rest tl) then rest else hd:rest
```

It says that removing the first duplicate of an empty list is the empty list. Removing the first duplicate of a tuple with a `fst` `x` entails removing the first duplicates of the tail, then either appending the first tuple to the result or not, based on whether it's in the tail.

---

Full code:

```
removeFirstDuplicate :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
removeFirstDuplicate [] = []
removeFirstDuplicate xs@(hd@(x, _):tl) =
    let
        rest = removeFirstDuplicate tl
    in
        if x `elem` (map fst rest) then rest else hd:rest                                                                                                                                               


main =
    let
        l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (2, 'f')]
    in
        do
            putStrLn $ show $ removeFirstDuplicate l
```

Output:

```
$ ghc duplicates.hs && ./duplicates 
[(1,'d'),(2,'f')]
```

---

Of course, it should be possible to solve it in linear time imperatively, or in *Θ(n log(n))* with a balanced tree: First iterate over the tuples, and map each `fst` item to the last index where it appears. Then iterate again, and retain only tuples whose `fst` item is at the index recorded as last.

Comment: Thank you @Ami Tavory that did the job nicely.